# Dice roll not working C++ deafult_random_engine

Tags: c++, random, numbers, simulation, dice

For some reason I keep getting `6` every time. I know of another way to do a random dice roll, but I wanted to learn how to use the `deafult_random_engine`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> diceRoll(1, 6);

    cout << "You rolled a " << diceRoll(randomGenerator) << endl;
}
```

But this bit of code works with the `time(0)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
// dice roll
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int x = 1; x < 2; x++){
        cout << 1+(rand()%6) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: start by not using `time()` as the seed.

Comment: I put a few different seeds in, 150, 165, 9050, but they all return a value of 1 for the roll

Comment: None of these comments or answers explains *why* `time(0)` is such a bad seed value. I wouldn't expect a decent seed initialization function to yield these repeatable results if they vary by a second or more. @MichaelSchroeder - could you provide your platform / compiler?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  It works fine for me on Visual C++ 2012, compiled in 32-bit.

Comment: I am using Code Blocks

Comment: I also posted the working dice roll using the time(0).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwSEbnJGR0&index=9&list=PLSPw4ASQYyynKPY0I-QFHK0iJTjnvNUys                                                                                         this is the tutorial that i was following

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly the use of `time(0)` as the culprit here.

You should probably opt for a method like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(std::random_device{}());
    // OR:
    // default_random_engine randomGenerator(
    //  (unsigned) chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    uniform_int_distribution<int> diceRoll(1, 6);

    cout << "You rolled a " << diceRoll(randomGenerator) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

While your original code always produced `6` on my system, this one seems a little more "adventurous":

```
pax> for i in {1..10}; do ./qq ; sleep 1 ; done
You rolled a 5
You rolled a 5
You rolled a 6
You rolled a 1
You rolled a 6
You rolled a 5
You rolled a 2
You rolled a 3
You rolled a 5
You rolled a 4
```

Comment: But time(0) works when I write it a different way without default_random_engine. How can I put script in a comment? I'm new...

Comment: So this must be a problem with my <random> library right?

Comment: what is std::random_device{}())

Comment: Because this just gives me 1 over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <random>
 #include <ctime>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
  mt19937 randomGenerator(time(0));
  uniform_int_distribution<int> diceRoll(1, 6);

  cout << "You rolled a " << diceRoll(randomGenerator) << endl;
 }
```